# Кодировка avito

Tags: python, кодировка, bs4

Всем привет! Делаю парсер авито, и данные записываю в excel. Но на выходе получаю:
[image: excel output]

```
def get_data(html):
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
avito = soup.find_all('div', class_="iva-item-body-R_Q9c")
for parser in avito:
    named = parser.find('h3').text
    purchase = parser.find('span', class_="price-text-E1Y7h text-text-LurtD text-size-s-BxGpL").text
    #avtor = parser.find('div', class_="iva-item-text-_s_vh iva-item-hideWide-oLeJu text-text-LurtD text-size-s-BxGpL").text

    print('Название: ' + named)
    #print('Имя продавца: ' + avtor)
    print('Цена: ' + purchase)



    saved_excel(named,purchase)

def saved_excel(named,purchase):
with open('output.xls', 'a',newline='',encoding='utf-8', ) as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerow(['название: '+named])
    writer.writerow(['Цена: ' + purchase])
```

Comment: Во-первых, csv-файлы должны иметь расширение csv, а не xls. Во-вторых, вы точно в Excel открываете файл с кодировкой utf-8?

Comment: да точно в excel)

Comment: Откройте в блокноте, проверьте кодировку там

Comment: А где получение `html`? Надеюсь, вы там `.content` обрабатываете, а не `.text`?

Comment: В блокноте кодировка работает.

Comment: А, ну для экселя же нужно `encoding='cp1251'` использовать - родную кодировку винды. А у питона родная кодировка `utf-8`.

Answer (score 0):

Данная проблема часто возникает непосредственно с самим excel при открытии csv файлов. Решение: импортировать csv в открытый excel файл (в мастере импорта можно будет выбрать кодировку).

https://office-guru.ru/excel/preobrazovyvaem-csv-v-excel-kak-importirovat-faily-csv-v-elektronnye-tablicy-excel-368.html (раздел: **Как импортировать CSV в Excel**)

PS - в большенстве случаев кодировка UTF-8 или windows-1251

Answer (score 0):

Подскажите пожалуйста, к читаемым классам идёт добавка, например class='price-text-**E1Y7h**' Они статичны или рандомно меняются?

Comment: если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы; если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос. а этот «ответ» пожалуйста удалите.